Upvoting again, rewarding a question just because it has been asked
In every case, a question, if it is useful or not, should be upvoted by any reaction of the community. A reaction, may it be a comment or an answer, shows some interest for the question, so, the questioning should be rewarded . I think, questioners should be encouraged this way. Down- or upvoting at will is another case, this shows a rating by consent or refusal.

What is the question here?

It is not question

The tag is feature-request.

[tag:feature-request] is for requests related to features that should be added to the network, not to request a specific kind of behaviour. Moreover, voting is considered to be anonymous. Regardless, a blanket request to upvote questions "in every case" would downgrade the quality of the content created. For most, voting represents some form of quality (it's different on Meta pages).

Please think about it. In fact, the database does overestimate anonymous ratings against personal ratings or the shown attention. I cannot look into your databases or algorithms, I just suspect, the statistics are a bit unbalanced. Take it as a well-meant suggestion.

Three downvoters... without any comment, who voted and why.. . A downvote should be reasoned. If not, it is of no significance . See?

As mentioned, voting is (and always will be) anonymous. If individuals disagree with your request, or if the question is not something they support, then they may show it in the form of a downvote. That is the case on Meta. On the main page, the same principles apply (anonymity, support, or whatever). Specific to your question, take it that (at least) 3 people do not support your request. They may not have better suggestions... they just don't support your request. There's no need to add a reason to that.

@Werner Unsupporting a question needs silence, not downvoting. Critisimn needs words. In fact, as my experience with databases taught me, unqualified and not commented values are useless, Your  concept of the database fails at this point: You* want to have qualified votes, but you are accepting unqualified votes. It is nothing about the whole concept, it's just a little fault, I liked to point out. In any way, a posted reaction of the community should lead to an upvote for a question. If not, your database does not work correctly. *(You or StackExchange..)

Hover over the upvote and downvote button. You'll see a justification pop up. That justification makes sense on the main site and should qualify as appropriate comment/criticism. On Meta, it is slightly different, as questions here relate to the main site, and are often also polling in nature (soliciting support for or against some thing). Finally, feature requests or often network-wide requests, as it pertains to the functionality of the site... not to behaviour of users.

for the record, I downvoted this question because this is meta and I do not agree with the feature request.

Please don't upvote unclear, fragmentary, off-topic or otherwise not useful questions.
This will prevent automatic processes like https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/auto-deleted-questions from doing its job and will result in a lot of low quality posts to remain on the site. This will dilute the information-to-noise ratio and make it harder for people to find useful questions and answers.

In fact, anonymous downvoting is "unclear, fragmentary, off-topic" and you have no control over this. I think, you might improve your voting system by taking my suggestion as well-meant. An anonymous downvote is not an evidence of expertise.

As mentioned above, your database has a little fault: The database accepts unqualified votes, which may be dropped in without any reason. By this, your database gets unreliable. At least, if or if not displayed, any voter should be obliged to explain his vote, occasionally to be seen by demand. Werner said, that votes should be anonymous. This is easy to implement.

@MBE: This makes no sense. It sounds like you request all votes to be explained. Because you can't really suggest that only downvotes be accompanied by reasoning, right? Otherwise any vote would be "unqualified." People vote for all kinds of reasons, not all of which requires them to consider adding an explanation. Moreover, it would clutter posts with unnecessary comments.

@Werner You misunderstood my suggestion. Please read again. Any formulated, displayed and posted reaction should gain a little more weight, than an anonymous dropped "like" or "unlike". That is, because the effort in a posted comment or answer should be higher  valued. But, let this be settled: It is a matter of your database designers. It is not only about Meta, I reckon, the system is the same in all of the sites of StackExchange. Shorter: A qualified reaction should be higher rated, than a anonymous vote. I think, this would improve the system.

@MBE: I get it now. Such a feature can't be implemented on a site-by-site basis, and would be something that requires consideration and implementation network wide. If you feel strong about such a suggestion, you'll have to present it much more clearly (together with an appropriate weight for commenting voters), plus motivate its reasoning on [meta.se]. Critique over there will be harsh though, so be prepared. Note that comments are considered fleeting on any site, even with incentive to clean them up (through flagging). How would that affect the motivation? 1/2

@MBE: ... and what would be considered a meaningful weight-carrying comment? As opposed to someone that just comments gibberish to make their vote weigh more. How would this affect reputation, since downvoting carries a penalty for the voter as well? It's these type of nuances that needs fleshing out before seeking network wide acceptance. In that regard, I think you'll see similar, if not harsher feedback from [meta.se] users. 2/2

@Werner Thanks. I haven't expected this to be easy.  In the end, no database is able to prevent gibberish. Anyway, I thank you for taking up the matter. As always, it is the conflict between truth and trolls. This is not manageable by databases.
